# Hibernate: is it possible to reduce file size of jar?

Tags: java, hibernate, desktop-application

I am working on a desktop application, I use Hibernate and HSQLDB. When I make my application a runnable jar file, it has a bigger fize size than I think. I see that the biggest part is from Hibernate and its dependencies. I am not sure if I need all of the Hibernate features. Is there a way to get rid of the parts of Hibernate and its dependency libraries which I don't use?

Answer (score 0):

Under the `/lib/` folder in Hibernate zip you will see a folder called `/required/`. For very basic Hibernate apps thats all you will need though you may need additional JARs for things such as JPA. I would start by only including the JARs in the `lib/required/` directory, see if your project works, and if it doesn't add what you need to get your project working again.

Comment: So, Hibernate uses all the "required" jars, and there is no way to reduce them?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. You might be able to get away with removing one of them but chances are that down the road new code you add will break since Hibernate won't be able to find the required JARs.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could use a tool to analyse your classes and dependencies (for e.g. http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/). Here is another post about it: [How do I find out what jar files are actually used when compiling a java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763710/how-do-i-find-out-what-jar-files-are-actually-used-when-compiling-a-java-project).

the other way is to remove some jars (or even single class files) and try whether your application is still working or  not. but i think this is not a very good way...

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a better tool for this than [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

> **ProGuard** is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused instructions. It renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods using short meaningless names. Finally, it preverifies the processed code for Java 6 or for Java Micro Edition.