# How to extract all used libraries from Java Maven web project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weblogic, wildfly-8

I have a web project built in Eclipse. It runs on a JBoss Wildfly 8 server and uses a number of the installed libraries on that server. Those libraries are not in the pom file as they are found through the reference to the Server runtime.

Now I want to deploy this war on a WebLogic, so I want to extract all used libraries.

How can I extract all the used Wildfly libraries (RestEasy, Jaxrs...) so I can put them in the lib folder of my war  which will be deployed on WebLogic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You tagged Maven. If you are using Maven for dependency management you should include the required JARs Wildfly provides as dependencies in your POM file.

[Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) makes it easy to find available versions and the POM definitions.

As referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1763736/4008877), Class Dependency Analyzer may help identify dependencies.

Comment: OK, sounds good for exporting but then I still need to find out which libraries are used... I hoped there would be some way of finding all referenced libraries for me.

Comment: Class Dependency Analyzer helps a bit... it shows the class or package dependencies, but it seems to be not able to find the jars that deliver the classes... Container is always empty. I did not find any possibility to tell the program to look for the containing jars in the modules folder of JBoss.